# Wrong Tax calculation

Tags: magento-1.9

We have setup 21% tax for Netherlands, and following is calculation for 1 order in backend :

Subtotal    €196.32
Shipping & Handling €7.40
Kosten betaalmethode    €7.40
Grand Total (Excl.Tax)  €209.84
Tax €44.11
Grand Total (Incl.Tax)  €253.95
Total Paid  €0.00
Total Refunded  €0.00
Total Due   €253.95

I understand that the payment charges above are shown incl tax so the Grand total excl tax = € 196,32 + € 7,40 + € 6,12 = 208,84 instead of € 211,12

But the issue is that the 21% VAT over € 209,84 should be: VAT € 44,07, But its shows VAT € 44,11

Can please anybody help how above calculation are correct ?

Comment: It looks like a round problem. the exkl. Tax amount seems to be round up.